# Is it always good to "try" to apply, despite a lack of spoken language skills?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

My problem is language.
My dream would be working in the UK, anyway although I have no particular problems in writing and reading, I have some lacks in spoken english.

Right now there is a nice job opportunity, anyway I fear that I will be discarded just for my spoken english skills.
Is it right to try anyway? Or is it better to just go when I feel myself ready?

What happens if I fail and then I return after one year? That company's recruiters will discard me regardless of my newly acquired experiences or they will not take into account the fact I already applied once?

Comment: I had the same problem, I always put fluent English on my resume. At the end they will talk to you at the interview, so they will know how fluent is your English, if you are not applying for an English teacher position, I think you should at least try. Most of the time is not the most important thing, have an accent or say some word badly, as long as you can communicate.

Comment: I would disagree with @peterPeterson slightly, in that I would not suggest writing 'fluent in English' on your resume or CV unless you actually were. If you are quite competent in the spoken language, note that. But I wouldn't suggest putting something in that may encourage a particular expectation, in this case that you are fluent in a language that you actually aren't. I do agree, however, that most times the main thing is your being able to communicate with others within the org. So go for it!

Comment: I agree, I would never put something fishy on my resume!:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You try and give it your best shot. The worst that happens is that they say "no", and if they say "no", you will be no worse off than you are today.

Recruiters are unlikely to remember anything about you after one year unless you did something memorable like being caught lying on your resume or you actually insulted one of them. They might have your resume still on file after one year but they'll be glad to get an updated resume from you. After all, they make their money pushing any valuable skills and experience you may have acquired in that year.

Don't sweat the spoken English part. As long as your written English is good - and the way you write your post indicates that, you have a fighting chance. I am an American but I would be initially in for some serious culture shock if I had to make out the Scottish dialect, or the Cockney accent or the Irish brogue :)